# Is there any way of passing variables to an included file in PHP?

Tags: php, include, parameter-passing

I have a class with a method which conditionally includes a file. I've tried declaring global variables, `eval(get_file_contents())`, etc., nothing seems to work. I want to use the local variables in the file I'm including.

Comment: use include_once or require

Comment: can you give more info on your problem

Comment: To access&manipulate global vars in local env (e.g. in a function) use: `foreach($GLOBALS as $k=>$v){ ${$k} = &$v; }` in the function where you need the vars. Keep an eye on variablesnames (prevent override!).

Comment: And dont use `eval`!! just include the file with `inlcude 'xyz.php';` and all global defined variables are accesable after the include (but there will be local not global variables then). Read about php references and variable scopes..

Comment: That's a horrible suggestion, @JustOnUnderMillions. There is absolutely no reason to loop over `$GLOBALS`, if he needs a specific variable in a function, he should pass them as parameter. All global variables are in an included file in the same scope available.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois way better than eval and it was just a comment, no proper answer. Note: He includes within a function, how can you manipulate $GLOBALS there ,without any kind of registry-class or so? I thing he should dig more into the way php works at all. Who tells him to `eval` in the first place!?!? --- php itself has some horrible implementaitons;) What about a proper answer from you?